# Jxls - cells not empty

Tags: excel, jxls

I'm using `jxsl` to write an `excel` with an `each-command` area.
The sheet ends up all right, but I have 2 issues:

1) The cells containing numbers cannot be added together with the SUM function. They are some kind of text, but the format of the cell is correct.
   If I click the cell and press ENTER it turns into a number.

2) Them empty cells are not really empty. If I try to count the not empty cells with COUNTA() all lines are counted.

The variable returns a String-Value or null.

Has anyone this issue?

The last two columns are added up with a COUNTA() formula. If I click one "empty" cell and press "DEL" the counting is reduced by one. This lead me to think the cell could contain a white space or so, but I checked with a macro `Debug.Print ">" & cell.value & "<"` and the output was `><`.

[template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAmBt.png)

The numbers are in german locale - the "," are used to represent double numbers.

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRn9n.png)

The formulas in the last row are `=SUM(F8:F13)` respectively `=COUNTA(J8:J13)` for the last two columns.

Comment: 1) Check the format of the cells in the Excel template to make sure it is number. Jxls should preserve the cell format from the template

Comment: Hi Leonid, the format in template is correct. And it is even shown correct in the new sheet. But even if I try to switch it to Text or Date or anything else, the cell do not change. I could provide the file, but I can't see a way to upload it here.

Comment: And to end it up: if I click the cells with numbers, press F2 to edit it and just press ENTER ... they start working as expected. They are suddenly recognized as number cells and the formula add them up.

Comment: You can try to re-evaluate all the formulas with POI evaluator before saving the workbook: workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll(); See http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html for detail